# Observing values on AVPlayerItem in iOS9

Tags: avfoundation, ios9, avplayeritem

I have an app that uses `AVPlayer` to play an `AVPlayerItem` (video) from a remote URL. In iOS 6-8 I have been observing the `AVPlayerItem's` value for `loadedTimeRanges` to notify me when the `playerItem` is ready to be played by the player. This also works when observing the value for the item's `duration`, I believe.

After updating to iOS 9 beta, none of the values on `AVPlayerItem` I observe ever makes it to the `observeValueForKeyPath`-method. Just as if I'm not observing them at all. I am still being notified by the values on `AVPlayer`, but not on `AVPlayerItem`. Could this be a bug, or did something change in the environment here? I can't find anything about this..

For clarification, in iOS 6-8 the videos are starting to play as soon as there are any loaded time ranges. In iOS9 I am never notified when any time ranges have been loaded.

**Update**

After observing the value `status` for `AVPlayerItem` I have now confirmed that the item's status is changed to `Failed`. By logging out the item's `NSError` after failing, I get this:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 
    "The operation could not be completed" 
    UserInfo=0x146023c90 {NSUnderlyingError=0x144f547d0 
    "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1022.)",
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-1022), 
    NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. In my case, loading the video was failing due to the new App Transport Security feature in iOS 9.

You can add a per-domain exception to your info.plist like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

If you need to load videos from arbitrary domains, you can disable App Transport Security altogether, although this is not recommended.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```