# iOS 9: Old project with AVPlayer stopped playing video - no error messages

Tags: ios, avfoundation, ios9, avplayer

This issue came about when I opened an old project that relies a lot on AVPlayers: none of the videos display or play, though no console messages show up and code-wise things appear normal. Here's some code that's exhibiting the issue for me:

```
            AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IMG_8481" withExtension:@"MOV"]];
            AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: player];
            [self.layer addSublayer: playerLayer];
            [player play];
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here but I don't get a video playing.

Things I've checked:
- the layer is visible (checked by setting its backgroundColor)
- the player is not nil, or being deallocated
- the currentItem property on the player is not nil
- the video file is one that was recorded on the iPhone, then pulled off with Image Capture, so should be good there.

Any ideas? I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

Use KVO to monitor the player's status. When you get a status of failed, check the AVPlayer's error property for more info. Info on observing at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW8.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to be notified for changes of the player status using KVO like this:

```
[self.playerItem addObserver:self 
      forKeyPath:@"status"
      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
      context:nil];
```

This method will be called when the status changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void  *)context {
    if (object == self.playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        // you can get status here
    }
}
```

If your code works fine in iOS 8 but not in iOS 9, you should confirm App Transport Security settings.
see: [Observing values on AVPlayerItem in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984433/observing-values-on-avplayeritem-in-ios9)